# About the definition of $L^{\infty}$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definition, normed-spaces

Let $\Omega$ a limited domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the space $L^{\infty}(\Omega)=\{f: \Omega\to\mathbb{R}  $ measurable $;  ||f||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}<\infty\}$. Then if a function $f \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, by definition of $L^{\infty}$ norm, $f$ is bounded a.e x, we can say that $\sup\limits_{\Omega} |f(x)| <\infty$ a.e.x or the last inequality is valid for all $x \in \Omega$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Writing "$\sup_{\Omega} |f(x)| < \infty$ a.e. $x$", "$f$ is bounded a.e. $x,$ "etc is an error. It will be helpful to you to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

The "functions" in $L^p$ spaces, including $L^\infty$, are actually equivalence classes, where $f$ and $g$ are equivalent if they are equal almost everywhere.  So any statement you make about $f(x)$ can only be interpreted in the "almost everywhere" sense.  However, for $f \in L^\infty$ you can choose a representative of the equivalence class that is bounded everywhere.  Namely, start with any representative, and change the value (say to $0$) on the set of measure $0$ where this representative's absolute value $> \|f\|_\infty$.

Comment: You would have a reference that speaks about the process you mentioned at the end of your text?

Comment: "However, for $ f \in L^{\infty}$  you can.... $>||f||_{\infty}$

Answer (score 1):

Only for almost all $x$.

This follows from the definition of the "norm". One possible (equivalent) definition is that $\|f\|_\infty$ is the smallest number $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le M$ for almost all $x$.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. You would have a counter-example?

Comment: Sure, take $f$ zero everywhere except at the integers. Note that "norm" means that it is not really a norm, because you are not considering the equivalence classes.